# Best practice for MySQL passwords in Docker

Tags: mysql, docker

I am currently playing with docker containers and mysql databases. Each application has its own mysql db in its own docker container. The application and the database share a network, the application itself is accessed via another network (traefik). this means that the mysql database is not accessible from the outside. How important is it to set secure passwords for the mysql instances? is there a best practice?

**Update**: Using now Docker secrets

Here is a sample **docker-compose.yaml** i use with nextcloud:

```
services: 
  nextcloud-db:
    image: mariadb
    container_name: nextcloud-db
    command: --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED --log-bin=ROW
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - /opt/docker/nextcloud/database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_root_password
      MYSQL_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_user_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: nextcloud
      MYSQL_USER: nextcloud
      MYSQL_INITDB_SKIP_TZINFO: 1
    secrets:
      - mysql_root_password
      - mysql_user_password



secrets:
  mysql_root_password:
    file: /opt/docker/secrets/mysql_root_password
  mysql_user_password:
    file: /opt/docker/secrets/mysql_user_password
```

You can create the secret files with:

```
openssl rand -base64 32 > /opt/docker/secrets/mysql_root_password
openssl rand -base64 32 > /opt/docker/secrets/mysql_user_password
```

Comment: can you share which blog did you follow? I am trying to do something similar and docker is a bit confusing. or at least that's what I feel.

Comment: @dexter:  Pretty much try and error. I usually build the containers with a docker-compose.yaml and expand them little by little. I started with Portainer, a really good GUI for Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always aim to have a strong password on MySQL, even if your app is in a local docker network.

You never know when your app environment changes in the future or what user will have access to that local network at some point.

Luckily it’s very easy to use secrets (which are really simple files containing passwords mounted in /secrets directory in your containers) with Docker swarm and Docker compose.

See an example here: https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2017/11/23/use-docker-secrets-with-mysql-on-docker-swarm/

Comment: thank you! i'm switching to docker secrets. seems to be the best way!

Comment: This is assuming that the local docker network is not safe. If it is not, then there are certainly bigger problems to deal with... because indeed the docker network is considered confidential, and having access to it is considered as having authorized access to everyting.